# Problem adding triples in rdflib.store.IOMemory

Tags: python, rdflib

Whenever I try to add triple into the store using following code it gives me following error. Could you please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

```
store = plugin.get('IOMemory',Store)()
store.add((abc, FOAF['knows'],def))

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\internetcode.py", line 114, in <module>
  store.add((abc, FOAF['knows'],def))
TypeError: add() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, you need to know that when python says that a method takes 3 arguments, it really means two argument plus the instance argument (usually `self`).  You are currently passing the instance (`store`) plus a three element tuple: `(abc, FOAF['knows'], def)`, which counts as one argument.  `store.add()` needs a third argument.  That's what the error message is trying to tell you.  I don't know what it needs, but the documentation should be able to explain further.

If nothing else, you can try `store.add((abc, FOAF['knows'], def), None)`, and see if that causes a new error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to pass at least 3 arguments. In the [documentation](http://www.rdflib.net/rdflib-2.4.0/html/public/rdflib.store.IOMemory.IOMemory-class.html) of that module you can see what arguments needs `add` method:

`(abc, FOAF['knows'],def)` is your triple? in that case you need two more: `context` and `quoted`

```
add(self, triple, context, quoted)
```

I've found some more information [here](http://www.rdflib.net/rdflib-2.4.0/html/public/rdflib.store.Store-class.html#add)

> add(self, (subject, predicate, object), context, quoted=False)
>
> Adds the given statement to a specific context or to the model. The
>   quoted argument is interpreted by formula-aware stores to indicate
>   this statement is quoted/hypothetical It should be an error to not
>   specify a context and have the quoted argument be True. It should also
>   be an error for the quoted argument to be True when the store is not
>   formula-aware.